# C# Ionic.Zip progressbar as background worker

Tags: c#, .net, ionic-zip

I got the following code:

```
        string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read("Fringe.S03E07.HDTV.XviD-LOL.zip"))
        {
            zip.ExtractProgress += ExtractProgress;
            foreach (ZipEntry file in zip)
            {
                file.Extract(path+"\\temp", ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
            }
        }  

    }

    public void ExtractProgress(object sender, ExtractProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Extracting_EntryBytesWritten)
        {
            //bytes transfered of current file
            label4.Text = e.BytesTransferred.ToString();
        }
        else if (e.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Extracting_BeforeExtractEntry)
        {
            //filename of current extracted file
            label2.Text = e.CurrentEntry.FileName;
        }
    }
```

when I click on the button, the form get stuck. I want to make the ExtractProgress as background worker but when I dont know how to convert the function to backgroundworker function because the ExtractProgress function require ExtractProgressEventArgs e and the backgroundworker_dowork function require DoWorkEventArgs e.

if someone can help me to convert it or to give me another solution it will be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: just put *all* the code in `button1_Click` into a method, and have `button1_Click` run that method in a `BackgroundWorker`. Try it and see how it works out.

Comment: In that case I have no Idea how to do it :/